# lastUpdated is not showing in maven-metadata.xml

Tags: maven, ant, ivy, archiva, maven-metadata

I have an issue with an artifact's maven-metadata.xml is not showing up.
Here is the environment i am working on:
Apache Archiva , Ivy, ant.

Problem: When I am Deploying artifact via the Web UI Form, I am able to see all the attributes in maven-metadata.xml.

```
<metadata>
  <groupId>twitter evt</groupId>
  <artifactId>authentication</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <latest>1.1</latest>
    <release>1.1</release>
      <versions>
       <version>LATEST</version>
       <version>1.0</version>
       <version>1.1</version>
      </versions>
   <lastUpdated>20090729142510</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

But when i deploy the artifact through ivy by command prompt (ant publish-latest -Dversion=1.0.3), artifact is updating fine with latest changes but artifact's maven-metadata.xml is missing  attribute with latest time stamp.

```
<metadata>
  <groupId>twitter evt</groupId>
  <artifactId>twitter_account_management</artifactId>
   <versioning>
     <latest>1.1.1</latest>
     <release>1.1.1</release>
        <versions>
          <version>LATEST</version>
          <version>1.0</version>
          <version>1.0.1</version>
          <version>1.0.2</version>
          <version>1.0.3</version>
          <version>1.0.4</version>
          <version>1.0.5</version>
          <version>1.1</version>
          <version>1.1.1</version>
       </versions>
   </versioning>
</metadata>
```

Here is my ant publish-latest target:

```
<target name="publish_latest" depends="_loadantcontrib,dist" >
  <ivy:settings file="${ivy.settings.dir}/ivysettings.xml" />
  <ivy:resolve file="${ant.dir}/ivy.xml" transitive="false" />
  <ivy:findrevision organisation="${ivy.organisation}" module="${ivy.module}" revision="latest.integration"/>
  <echo message="looking in: ${basedir}/${build_distdir}/${jar_tcs_libdir}/${component.distfilename}/${component_version}/" />
  <ivy:publish resolver="ibiblio" artifactspattern="${basedir}/${build_distdir}/${jar_tcs_libdir}/${component.distfilename}/${component_version}/[artifact].[ext]" pubrevision="${version}" overwrite="true" update="true"/>
</target>
```

Please help me on this issue, I struck at this point in process of getting the latest artifact.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this aspect of Ivy, but there's potential that it's a bug in Ivy that doesn't write the field.

One potential way to correct this is to turn on Archiva's automated metadata correction. Try enabling the *metadata-updater* consumer in the *Consumers of Known Content* section at the bottom of the *Repository Scanning* admin page, then deploy the artifact again.

More information is available here: http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.3/adminguide/consumers.html

Comment: hi brett, thanks for your message, I tried disabling meta-updater , removed existing artifact and maven-metadata.xml and re-enabled meta-updater in archiva.
every thing is working fine but not getting <lastupdated> attribute.